# How to connect amazon aurora rds postgresql with Parse server running in a EKS cluster?

Tags: amazon-eks, parse-server, amazon-aurora

I have been trying to get parse server up on my EKS cluster. but the pods fail giving the error no database "dbname" does not exist. I have another app deployed on the server (nakama game server) that is connected to an RDS postgreSQL. the security group used for both RDS are exactly the same. so i am failing to understand why parse server is unable to find the database.

here is the error thrown by the pod--->

```
error: database "database-2" does not exist
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/parse-server/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/parse-server/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (/parse-server/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/parse-server/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
  length: 95,
  severity: 'FATAL',
  code: '3D000',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'postinit.c',
  line: '989',
  routine: 'InitPostgres'
}
```

here is the config.js -->

```
const ParseServer = require("parse-server").ParseServer;
    const databaseUri =
      "postgresql://username:password@database-2.cluster-cum5cpuwordc.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/database-2";
    const parseServerConfig = {
      appId: "assessment-service",
      masterKey: "masterKey",
      clientKey: "client-key",
      appName: "relive",
      cloud: "./cloud/main",
      // serverURL: "http://<your-parse-server-url>/parse",
      databaseURI: databaseUri,
    };
```

please let me know if you need any more information.

rechecking the database uri

Comment: i tried creating a debug pod in the same node group, and with psql tried connecting to the aurora db from within the debug pod. which threw the same error of database doesnt exist. so it seems to be some problem with url of db.